# Load testing for API project using controller and agents(distributed load testing)

Tags: visual-studio-2012, load, load-testing, performance-testing

I have an API project which writes data in files or SQL Server. These data are written in asynchronous manner.i.e. first data is written in buffer and then buffer writes those data into file or SQL server. I want to do load testing for this client API using visual studio 2012 and controller and agent. I want to calculate throughput and response time. For this, I have written a unit test which uses that API and send data. Now, using load testing, I can get number of messages written per second(i.e. tests/second) but it only gives numbers of messages it dropped in buffer and does not give messages written in file or database per second as the system is asynchronous.So how can I calculate response time and throughput for the entire process. i.e. start from when the client API called till the message is written in text file or database.

I am new in load testing.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you'll need to measure, not calculate.

Use a web performance test. It can record a transaction and log the measured time.

Start the transaction when you invoke the unit test. You'll need a mechanism to detect when the write has finished and tell the web performance test to end the transaction.